# Correlation of categorical data to binomial response in R

Tags: r, correlation, categorical-data, fixed-effects-model, log-linear

I'm looking to analyze the correlation between a categorical input variable and a binomial response variable, but I'm not sure how to organize my data or if I'm planning the right analysis.

Here's my data table (variables explained below):

```
species<-c("Aaeg","Mcin","Ctri","Crip","Calb","Tole","Cfus","Mdes","Hill","Cpat","Mabd","Edim","Tdal","Tmin","Edia","Asus","Ltri","Gmor","Sbul","Cvic","Egra","Pvar")
scavenge<-c(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1)
dung<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)
pred<-c(0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)
nectar<-c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)
plant<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
blood<-c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
mushroom<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
loss<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0) #1 means yes, 0 means no
data<-cbind(species,scavenge,dung,pred,nectar,plant,blood,mushroom,loss)
data #check data table
```

**data table explanation**

I have individual species listed, and the next columns are their annotated feeding types. A 1 in a given column means yes, and a 0 means no. Some species have multiple feeding types, while some have only one feeding type. The response variable I am interested in is "loss," indicating loss of a trait. I'm curious to know if any of the feeding types predict or are correlated with the status of "loss."

**thoughts**

I wasn't sure if there was a good way to include feeding types as one categorical variable with multiple categories. I don't think I can organize it as a single variable with the types c("scavenge","dung","pred", etc...) since some species have multiple feeding types, so I split them up into separate columns and indicated their status as 1 (yes) or 0 (no). Examples I find don't quite have comparable data... and I'm happy for suggestions.

Any help or pointing in the right direction is much appreciated!

edit: I was recommended to re-post this question here from the original StackOverflow post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58903067/correlation-of-categorical-data-to-binomial-response-in-r)

Comment: It sounds like you might want some sort of regression, but it's not clear exactly what.